# Class order scanning bug in Neo4J OGM

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am having issues with the order classes are scanned in Neo4 OGM.

Take the following minimal Spring Data Rest + Spring Boot application:

```java
@NodeEntity("Country")
public class Country extends CountryRevision {
}

@NodeEntity("CountryRevision")
public class CountryRevision extends RevisionEntity<CountryRevision> {
    String name;
}

public abstract class RevisionEntity<T> {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    String id;

    @Relationship
    T previousRevision;

}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "countries", path = "countries")
public interface CountryRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Country, String> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "countryRevisions", path = "country-rev")
public interface CountryRevisionRepository extends Neo4jRepository<CountryRevision, String> {}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackageClasses = DemoApplication.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = DemoApplication.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When POSTING to /country-rev, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Field previousRevision not found in class com.example.demo.CountryRevision or any of its superclasses
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassInfo.getField(ClassInfo.java:601) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.FieldInfo.readProperty(FieldInfo.java:411) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
```

What is really strange is that if I modify the "Country" class name to something else, like "Toto", everything works fine.

I debugged the way the OGM is initialized. It looks like depending on the classname, the map containing all OGM ClassInfos will be processed in a different order (in DomainInfo.prepareClass()), which will produce different results.

My question is: is there anything wrong with the previous example, or is this a bug in the OGM?

Comment: That is really odd behaviour and shouldn't happen because the whole class hierarchies will get rebuild if any class gets added while scanning. Will investigate this. Am I right to assume that the `@Relationship String previousRevision` points to something else than a `String`?

Comment: Yes the ```previousRevision``` type should be a ```T```. But I wanted to make sure that even if it was a simple type, the bug would still exist, hence a ```String``` in the example. Would you like me to create an issue on Github for this?

Comment: Can you please post to GitHub what you are posting to the URL, Martin?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely an OGM issue which I reported here:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/704

Comment: Thanks for reporting this!